# Use pivot_table and groupby for calculation (groupby.mean() doesn't address unique 'batch')

Tags: python, pandas

I have a big df that looks something like this (small part):

```
Product   Batch   Inv_type        Item      Total_cost
Big Boy    1,000   Packaging       Cans        664
Big Boy    1,000   Raw Material   Flour        800
Big Boy    1,000   Packaging       Label       300
Big Boy    1,000   Raw Material    Sugar       900
Big Boy    1,001   Packaging       Cans        782
Big Boy    1,001   Raw Material   Flour        560
Big Boy    1,001   Packaging       Label       300
Big Boy    1,001   Raw Material    Sugar       522
Hit Ton    1,002   Raw Material   Flour        560
Hit Ton    1,002   Packaging       Label       300
Hit Ton    1,002   Raw Material    Sugar       522
```

It's basically a bill of materials list. Each product is composed of multiple items with different values and are either packaging or raw materials.

```
I need this: 
  Sum of all Packing Costs / count of unique Batch #'s 
  Sum of all Raw Material Costs/ count of unique Batch #'s
```

So it would look like this (Parentheses to show formula only):

```
Product   Inv_Type    Avg_cost_per_batch
Big Boy  Packaging             1,023        (2,046 / 2)
         Raw Material          1,391        (2,782 / 2)
  
HIT TON  Packaging              300        (300 / 1)
        Raw Material          1,082        (1,082 / 1)
```

This would give me the average total packaging cost and total raw materials per batch per product.

I would like to add the `Avg_cost_per_batch` to a new column `df['Avg_batch_cost']`, so I can graph the average costs for each product by this breakdown.
It can be added at each line where the Product name is if that is best for `'Tidy Data'` format.

Here is what I have tried:

first drop duplicates

```
   dropdups =  df.drop_duplicates(subset='Batch', inplace=True, ignore_index=True)
```

then pivot

```
pvdups = pd.pivot_table(dropdups, values='Batch', index='Product', aggfunc='count')
```

This appears to get me the number of unique batch counts by product

Then I group original df:

```
prod_totals = df.groupby(['Product', 'Inv_type']).sum()['Total_cost']
```

So how do I take the pivot table df and the groupby series and to create an average cost broken down by product using the total cost shown / count of unique batch number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use [`pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.1/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) to aggregate `'Total_cost'` with [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sum.html) and `'Batch'` with [`nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.nunique.html).
- Then divide the two columns to get the desired output.

```py
# aggregate sum of Total_cost and the unique count of Batch
g = df.groupby(['Product', 'Inv_type']).agg({'Total_cost': sum, 'Batch': 'nunique'})

# calculate Avg_cost_per_batch
g['Avg_cost_per_batch'] = g.Total_cost.div(g.Batch)

# display(g)
                      Total_cost  Batch  Avg_cost_per_batch
Product Inv_type                                           
Big Boy Packaging           2046      2              1023.0
        Raw Material        2782      2              1391.0
Hit Ton Packaging            300      1               300.0
        Raw Material        1082      1              1082.0
```

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @chasedcribbet glad it works for you. I just needed to see what the expected output was.